# Disabling Linux driver for Arduino issue

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arduino, driver

I'm writing a kernel module which will be kind of a driver for my Chinese Arduino.
At one moment I had to disable existing arduino driver and make sure that arduino is not determined by system. I did it with rmmod command. Unplugged and plugged in my arduino. But it still determined in /dev/ as ttyUSB0, same as it was before.

Does it mean that I have more drivers on my system which I don't know about? Or every hardware plugged in usb port will be determined as a file regardless of driver existence? 0_0

Also, of course I have an arduino ide installed on my machine. Maybe there is a built-in driver? If so, how can I disable it without removing ide?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that I have more drivers on my system which I don't know
>   about?

Kernel may be configured to use a particular driver while user space still might change that.

The manual way: rmmod your driver, unplug Arduino, check system log with dmesg. Plug in Arduino, check dmesg again. Automated way: use `usb-devices` script from `usbutils` package (`apt-get install usbutils`) to list usb devices and the drivers associated with them.

After you find the associated driver, most likely `ch341`, `rmmod` it, or add to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` to disable loading of this module permanently.

Comment: Oh. Used dmesg and lsmod several times and found that: 

1)I rmmod my driver. Arduino disappeared from /dev/, it's a good sign.

2)Plugged in my Arduino. Looked lsmod. Arduino driver(ch341.ko) registered automatically after plugging Arduino in.

This is dmesg output after I plugged in my Arduino:
http://pastebin.com/JwjjdAuJ

Comment: @kekyc sudo rmmod ch341

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks. But it can't rmmod driver permanently. Can I disable automated registering of this driver somehow?

Comment: @kekyc add ch341 to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist

Comment: except I don't have blacklist file at /etc/modprobe.d :)
My system is debian wheezy.

Comment: @kekyc Please follow [these](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting) instructions